# How to create/work with layered images using Lua/Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Suppose I want an animated smiley face composed to 2 layers: the face background + face foreground.

The background layer is a simple color/texture.
The foreground layer is the animated layer (animated smiling, crying, laughing...etc).

How can i write this up in Lua such that Corona will treat these layers as a single object/entity? I would like a single entity to work with (for collision, animated movements, ...etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a [displayGroup](http://blog.anscamobile.com/2012/02/corona-display-groups-101/).

Something like this:

```
local smiley = display.newGroup()
local emotion = display.newImage("happy.png")
local background = display.newImage("background.png")

smiley:insert(background)
smiley:insert(emotion)

-- moving smiley will also move background and emotion
-- because they are attached to the smiley displayGroup
smiley.x = 100
smiley.y = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you out.

```
smiley:insert(1,background)
smiley:insert(2,emotion)
```

Greater the number more upfront is the image