# How can i set my button image on top of background image in Corona?

Tags: image, background, lua, coronasdk

Here is my image display objects:

```
   local background=display.newImage("background.png")
   local buttonImage1 = display.newImage("start.jpg")
```

I want the image of button object to be on top of the background image. How can i do that?

EDIT: Problem Solved

I used director class and with director class you should insert your display objects in order in localGroup in order to see them.

```
     localGroup:insert(background)
     localGroup:insert(buttonImage1)
```

Comment: search first, ask if you don't find answers. this is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378308/how-to-create-work-with-layered-images-using-lua-corona-sdk

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language. I searched first but not with layer topic. Hence i couldn't find it. Anyway, thanks for the link.

Comment: no worries, hopefully that gives you what you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, if you want to know another way...

```
buttonImage1:toFront()
```

will do it.